# How to append a file to an existing zip file/folder

Tags: matlab, zip

Is there a way to append a file to an existing zip file/folder?

[`zip(zipfilename,filenames)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zip.html) would overwrite the original *zipfilename*.

I am using Windows 10 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: According to the documentation, there is no option to append a file to an existing zip file using `zip` function. I though of using JAVA, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266409/how-do-i-update-a-pre-existing-jar-file), it is not possible using `JarOutputStream`. You better look for command line tool (execute  using `system('command...')`).

Comment: @Rotem: Thanks for the tip. I'll look into using powershell.

Comment: @Rotem: I think [`java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/package-summary.html) is able to add file to an existing zip file. But its `.write()` requires an `uint8` array as input. If I want the file, created with data in Matlab workspace, to be a csv file, would you have any tip for me as to what bytes array to use as input? (I can ask a sperate question if you have comments.) Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Save the file as CSV, and read the file content as binary data of  type `uint8`. Example: `f = fopen('a.csv', 'r');data = fread(f, '*uint8');fclose(f);`. Write `data` to a new entry in the ZIP file.

Comment: @Rotem: I see. Is there a way to avoid saving a file to harddrive first?

Comment: It requires some programming effort. You can cast a charter array to `uint8`, for example: `data = uint8(sprintf('%d, %d\r\n', 10, 20));`. Did you find a solution using JAVA ("append a file to an existing zip file")?

Comment: @Rotem: I came across the function when reading about serializing data in Matlab. I'll give it a try. Would you like me to ask a separate question and maybe your comments can be collected into an answer?

Comment: I recommend you to post your own answer if you find a solution for appending a file to an existing zip file. I don't want to collect my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
system(['powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Compress-Archive -update ',...
         filename,' ',...
         zipfilename]);
```

works.

---

Alternatively, as @Rotem pointed out, and in some situations more suitable, we can use Java's [`ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/package-summary.html) as long as we convert data to binary first.

If we start with a file test.csv, then the contained string can be read into an `uint8` array by

```
filename = 'test.csv';  % change filename as needed.
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
data = fread(fid , '*uint8');
fclose(fid );
```

If we start with data in a Matlab Workspace, we need to convert the data into the format we desire in the eventual output file and then convert it to binary. For example, if the desired compressed file is a .csv file, in other words, formatted text, we can prepare the string output with [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and convert it to the corresponding `uint8` array such as

```
data = uint8(sprintf('%d, %d\r\n', [1,2;3,4]));
```

Following the above, one can use Java's [`ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/package-summary.html) to output to an existing zip file. Example below.

```
filename='test.csv'; % change filename of zip entry as needed
zipfilename='test.zip'; % change filename as needed
fos = java.io.FileOutputStream(zipfilename);
zos = java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(fos);
ze  = java.util.zip.ZipEntry(filename);
% zos.setLevel(9); % optional
zos.putNextEntry(ze);
zos.write(data, 0, numel(data));
zos.finish;
zos.close;
```

The benefit of this approach is that, if the data starts off in the current Matlab Worksapce, no additional file needs to be created, which would have required additional i/o use 3 times (in the above example, write test.csv, read csv, delete csv).

Another benefit is that the this method does not require powershell which is OS dependent -- not available in earlier Windows versions for example.

If the data starts off in an external file with Windows 10, as specified in the OP, then the 1st method is more expedient.

*Note: Additional information on reading from the zip file or reading file list from zip file can be found [here](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/savezip-utility) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10945-read-files-in-zip-file-without-unzipping).*